# How to get values from database and display in android application

Tags: android

I am creating a Quiz application. Questions are added thru web form. I am using Mysql and ruby on rails for doing so..... I would like to display the questions and its options in android application with next and previous options. I am very new to android. Can somebody please tell me how do i do this.

Comment: what api REST, SOAP or what on your web end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to generate a XML file and to parse the value in the android application.

Use the sax parser to parse the values:
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

Here is an example on how to parse:
http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/parsing_xml_on_android/
http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

Here is the solution to create a wizard with previous and next buttons:
[Using ViewFipper in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365682/using-viewfipper-in-android)

Hope the above links will help u!

Comment: I would suggest JSON as opposed to xml.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Grott suggests, you should expose a Web service (REST preferred) from your Web application. You can then use HttpClient in Android to make Web service calls to get the data you seek.